# Doubled stack snippet buttons

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Sometimes after I post a comment or edit the question or answer, the buttons below the stack snippets in the question get duplicated.

[image]

I haven't been able to reproduce this reliably, but I first noticed it in the last day or two.

Comment: It happens to me on Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) on Win 10, usually when I scroll it off-screen and back on.

Comment: I've seen this too, but only in Chrome

Comment: I'm using Chrome as well, so it might be Chrome-specific.

Comment: Today I saw a triple!

Comment: I've just seen this too - it seems to happen when there are other edits pending which have been edited using the snippet - the one I saw was badly formatted so I clicked to edit, saw another edit waiting for approval then looked at it to see if they were doing the same as I was going to do, tidy the code. They were, so I got out and got double buttoned! Chrome too.